# synchronized listviews in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, scrollview

I'm making an app which is meant to work in PhoneGap, everything is going good so far except for the fact that I'm using [jQuery Mobile scrollview](http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/) and although it works pretty well, a problem appears and I don't understand how's that even possible.

I have this:

```
<div data-role="content">
        <div id="a" class="content_div">
            <div data-scroll="y">
                <ul id="recom-news" data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
                    <li><a href=""></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="b" class="content_div">
            <div data-scroll="y">
                <ul id="impresa-categories" data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
                    <li><a href="">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="c" class="content_div">
            <div data-scroll="y">
                <ul id="mas-secs" data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I hide each `content_div` and show another one so I can keep the header static because other solutions didn't work so well.

The problem is that if I scroll the first list, loaded via AJAX, the second `listview` gets scrolled the same way, the same happens if I don't make the AJAX call and just scroll the second list, the third scroll by the same amount.

I'm going crazy because the demos on the website make this without a hiccup.

Comment: Hiding the lists using .hide()?

Comment: yes, I hide all of them and then show the one I want to work with, like this: $('div.content_div').hide();$('div#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show();